# Resource monitoring on a linux machine

Tags: linux, resource-monitor, resource-usage

I know that there is a graphical application to see the resource usage of a ubuntu machine.

I also think I can use [htop](https://htop.dev/) for something similar.

I am going to access a remote computer (so probably wont have access to GUI). Is there any way I can get these resource usage numbers (memory, cpu, gpu) into a file so that I can record that?

A simple way would be ideal

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729720/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-top-command-in-a-file-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `top` command to write to a file.

```bash
top -n 1 -b >> resources.log
```

`-n` is how many times you want to run the command and `-b` is telling the command to run in batch-mode which is recommended for writing to a file with this command.